# Docker: permission on file created by npm inside the container

Tags: file, permissions, npm, docker, sails.js

I have a Dockerfile to create a dev enviroment to develop a sailsJS app.
I just mount my source code into the container. I make my Git commit on my host machine but i would like to execute all my npm command in the container.

I have the following Dockerfile and i am running Docker (1.4.1) in ubuntu 14.10:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

### Utils ###
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential git wget tar vim supervisor

### MongoDB ###
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
RUN echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org
RUN mkdir -p /data/db

### NodeJS ###
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN wget -O node http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.33/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN tar xf node
RUN mv node-v0.10.33-linux-x64 /usr/local/node
RUN ln -s /usr/local/node/bin/* /usr/local/bin

### Supervisord ###
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

### Project ###
RUN npm install -g sails bower
WORKDIR /opt/sails

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]

EXPOSE 27017 1337
```

I run my container with the following command :

```
docker run -d -ti -p 1337:1337 -p 27017:27017 -v ~/dev/pinne:/opt/sails --name test-app loikg/sailsjs-mongo
```

The problem is that when I use command with npm inside the container that create files like `sails genearet api` I don't have the writing permission on them in the host machine.
How can i solve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users and Groups do not sync from host->container.

Your services in the container are running as root (UID:0 GID:0).    Any files created by root in the container will need root access on the host.

One solution is to create a UID/GID inside the container that matches the UID/GID on the host.   Then all your processes inside the container need to use that UID/GID so the files have the correct ownership/permissions.

Remember, it's UserID not user name.   And GroupID not group name.   The names need not match, only the numeric ID's.

It's kind of a pita.   You will have to change your dockerfile to add the user, make sure your processes that create files are run with the correct uid, etc.

Comment: How can you do this if you don't know which user on the host will be running the container up front?

Answer (score 1):

One of the workarounds is to use overlapping volumes, e.g.

```
... -v ~/dev/pinne:/opt/sails:ro -v /opt/sails/node_modules ...
```

would allow writing to `/opt/sails/node_modules`. The downside is that the changes will be lost upon the container termination (unless you copy the volumes data via `--volumes-from`).  Another caveat AFAIR is that the path (`~dev/pinne/node_modules` -> `/opt/sails/node_modules`) should exist for this technique to work.